# How to access Express 4 req.body object using Busboy

Tags: node.js, express, routes, multipartform-data

I need a simple way to access multipart form data in the req object using busboy-connect. I'm using Express 4, which now needs modules for previously built-in functionality.

I want the req.body object to be available in my routes, but the busboy.on('field') function is async and doesn't process all form data before passing it off to continue down the code.

There is a middleware module built on top of busboy called [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), which gets the req.body object before getting to the route, however it overrides the ability to define the busboy.on('file') event from within the route.

Here's my broken code:

```
// App.js

app.post(/users, function(req, res, next){

  var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

  // handle text field data (code taken from multer.js)
  busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, valTruncated, keyTruncated) {
    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(fieldname)) {
      if (Array.isArray(req.body[fieldname])) {
        req.body[fieldname].push(val);
      } else {
        req.body[fieldname] = [req.body[fieldname], val];
      }
    } else {
      req.body[fieldname] = val;
      console.log(req.body);
    }
  });

  busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

    tmpUploadPath = path.join(__dirname, "uploads/", filename);
    targetPath = path.join(__dirname, "userpics/", filename);

    self.imageName = filename;
    self.imageUrl = filename;

    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tmpUploadPath));
  });

  req.pipe(busboy); // start piping the data.

  console.log(req.body) // outputs nothing, evaluated before busboy.on('field') 
                        // has completed.
 });
```

***UPDATE***
I'm using connect-busboy. I used this middleware code in my express setup file to give me access to the req.body object within my route. I can also process the file upload from within my route and have access to the req.busbuy.on('end').

```
 // busboy middleware to grab req. post data for multipart submissions.
 app.use(busboy({ immediate: true }));
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
     // console.log(fieldname, val);
     req.body[fieldname] = val;
   });

   req.busboy.on('finish', function(){
     next();
   });
 });
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue do you mind explaining how this code works? I have all my requests handled in separate routes and this solution doesn't work for my code. Perhaps if I had a better understanding of what your doing this would help me resolve my issue! This is my first node project.

Comment: @JeffPowers I could not get the middleware to work like I thought I had. There is no current solution to parse incoming Multipart data in "different" locations, such as only parse the fields, then do something with the fields data, then parse the file later, then call busboy.on("finish"). Please see my post here:http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/239170/how-to-parse-multipart-field-file-data-separately
let me know if you find anything. I ended up putting a ton of logic in my controller..not a good design choice but I gave up.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion I actually switched out busboy for multer: https://github.com/expressjs/multer. It was much simpler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding:

```
busboy.on('finish', function() {
  // use req.body
});
```

Comment: This was the clue I needed. I edited the OP to reflect my solution. It is middleware but I don't think it slows down incoming posts.

Comment: You could shorten your solution down to just `req.busboy.on('finish', next);`

Comment: I ran into another issue. I am trying to keep proper Separation of Concerns within my node app. So far my flow is like this: 
1. app.js: setup express middleware to get req.body from multipart data. I have to use immediate = true.
2. routes.js: define the /post route, pass it off to controller.
3. controller.js: use the req.body object to format data, create a new model object, call model.save(req.body) (which begins the picture upload process).
4. model.js: uses busboy+req.body data to upload picture to server.

Is there a way to process the req.body first, then pass to file upload event?

Comment: @mscdex I am using reCaptcha with a route that uses busboy and I need to a value from req.body to do verification before doing anything with uploads, the question is accessible from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467728/apply-recaptcha-v2-to-expressjs-route-that-handles-file-upload-using-busboy , would be glad if you could have a look. Cheers.